# Fire different methods depending upon duration of button click in android

Tags: android, button, onclick

I am relatively new to android. I was thinking of adding a functionality in which two different types of event occur depending upon the duration for which the button is pressed. Is such a functionality possible?
Say if the user presses the button for three seconds it should open a settings menu and otherwise it should search music in you phone. I am not concerned about what to do. I need to know if such a thing where I can detect the duration is possible

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe in your case will be sufficient to implement onClick and onLongClickListener

```
Button someButton = findViewById(R.id.button);

// fire this listener when user click on button
someButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener({...}));

// fire this listener when user do long click on Button
someButton.setOnLongClickListener(new OnLongClickListener({...}));
```

In this case you have two options, first is simple click and second is standard long click. I think it will be suitable solutions for your problem. But if you need more specific solutions, let's say for different times then you should implement OnTouchListener and handle touch events depends on your intention.

Comment: A question I would like to ask is that we write these two methods in onClick() method of my mainactivity?

Comment: You should add this method in onCreate method. Or you can implements OnClickListener i OnLongClickListener and then implements methods onClick and onLongClick see android docs for references.

Answer (score 1):

`View.setOnClickListener` and `View.setOnLongClickListener` is what you need.

If you want to find the duration, you would have to write your own `View` subclass. I suggest starting with `Button` and using listeners.